# Exceptions with JAVA loan calculator using JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, exception, jframe, calculator

I think I almost got it if I can just get rid of a few exceptions the program gives me when I try to run it. Here's the code I have:

```
package RandomMathGame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RandomMathGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandomProblemGenerator randomProblems = new RandomProblemGenerator(10);
        final int numberProblems = 10;
        int correctScore = 0;
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
       int answer;
        int correctAnswer;
        JLabel[] mathProblems = new JLabel[numberProblems];
        final JTextField[] mathAnswers = new JTextField[numberProblems];
        JLabel[] correctYesNo = new JLabel[numberProblems];
        final JLabel score = new JLabel(correctScore + "/10");
        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberProblems; i++)
        {
            final int X = randomProblems.createNumberX();
            final int Y = randomProblems.createNumberY();

            mathProblems[i] = new JLabel("" + X + " * " + Y + " = ");
            mathAnswers[i] = new JTextField();


             answer = Integer.parseInt(mathAnswers[i].getText());
             correctAnswer = X * Y;

            if (answer == correctAnswer)
            {
                correctYesNo[i] = new JLabel("Correct answer; good job!");
                correctScore = correctScore + 1;
            }
            else
            {
               correctYesNo[i] = new JLabel("Incorrect answer; try again!");

            }
             panel.add(mathProblems[i]);
             panel.add(mathAnswers[i]);
             panel.add(correctYesNo[i]);
            }

        final int temp = correctScore;
      submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                score.setText("Score: " + temp + "/10");
            }
        });



        panel.add(submit);
        panel.add(score);

        JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame();
        gameFrame.setTitle("Random Math Game");
        gameFrame.setSize(150, 150);
        gameFrame.setVisible(true);
        gameFrame.setContentPane(panel);



        }
  }
```

And these are the exceptions it's giving me when I run it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at RandomMathGame.RandomMathGame.main(RandomMathGame.java:33)
Java Result: 1
```

I'm crunched for time, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   String answerStr = mathAnswers[i].getText();

    if(answerStr.isEmpty()){

          correctYesNo[i] = new JLabel("Not a valid answer/answer field empty!");
    } else {

         answer = Integer.parseInt(answerStr);
         correctAnswer = X * Y;
         //Rest of your code goes here
    }
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Got me past that exception. Thanks.

Comment: @Commandrix Is this what you are looking at? If this solves your question accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get from a field you just created which is blank.

```
mathAnswers[i] = new JTextField();
answer = Integer.parseInt(mathAnswers[i].getText());
```

So in this you are just checking from wrong place.
Seems like on first step you want to create the text fields and the second line should be there at some other event.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
answer = Integer.parseInt(mathAnswers[i].getText());
```

Is what's causing the error. This is because one of your textfields is blank. Do some validation before accepting user input, unless you want your application to go awry.